# Function to sort list of lists into groups that share an item

Tags: python, function, sorting, nested-lists, custom-lists

My code is intended to sort a list of lists into the following *examples.*

I would like to group all [Y,x,x]'s with each other.

```
C = [[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[7,8,9],[1,2,4],[4,5,6]]
```

Intended Output

*Notice that my **Y** is bolded*

sorted C = [[**1**,2,3],[**1**,2,4],[**4**,5,7],[**4**,5,6],[**7**,8,9]]

```
c = [[4,5,10],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,7,9],[1,2,8],[4,5,9],[1,7,8],[4,5,12],[9,8,7]]
sc = []

def sorting():
    
    for a in range(0, len(c)):
        for b in c[a+1:]:
            # prevent duplicates
            if b not in sc:
                if c[a] not in sc:
                    if c[a][0] == b[0]:
                        sc.append(b)
                        sc.append(c[a])
    for z in c:
        if z not in sc:
            for a in range(0, len(sc)):
                if sc[a][0] == z[0]:
                    if sc.count(z) < 1:
                        # insert missing list into intended location
                        sc.insert(a, z)
    # Append lists that may have been missed (eg. [9,8,7])                    
    for zz in c:
        if sc.count(zz) < 1:
            sc.append(zz)

sorting()
print(sc)
```

**Error Output**

This function has a semantic bug as it is outputting a [4,x,x] in the wrong location. As shown in the example all [Y,x,x]'s are supposed to be grouped together.

[**[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 10]**, [1, 7, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 7, 8], [1, 2, 8], **[4, 5, 12], [4, 5, 9],** [9, 8, 7]]

### Question

*What would a more professional function look like to sort my lists as intended?*

*What mistakes am I doing that causes an invalid output?*

Comment: is implementing your own sorting algorithm necessary? or would using the [built in `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) be what you are looking for?

Comment: Are you specifically forbidden from using functions like `sort` and `sorted`?  If not, the "professional" solution would be to do something like `sc = sorted(c)`.  :)

Comment: If you're required to implement your own sorting logic from scratch, I'd recommend doing a little research on standard sorting strategies and trying to implement one of those rather than trying to invent your own.  A selection sort would be pretty similar to what you're attempting but simpler -- loop over the list, grab the smallest element and append it to the result, repeat to find the next-smallest element, repeat until done.

Comment: Will there never be overlap between the groups? What happens if you have C = [[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[7,8,9],[1,2,4],[4,5,6],[1,2,4]]. Where the last group has a 1 and a 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use lambda function to the sort function, in order to sort by the first element only.
try this:

```
c = [[4,5,10],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,7,9],[1,2,8],[4,5,9],[1,7,8],[4,5,12],[9,8,7]]

a = sorted(c, key=lambda parameter: parameter[0])   # sort by first element in item
print(a)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 7, 9], [1, 2, 8], [1, 7, 8], [4, 5, 10], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 9], [4, 5, 12], [9, 8, 7]]
```